# Dynamic Image Ouputs in Gradio

Tags: python, image, visualization, huggingface, gradio

I want to create a Gradio Application which takes in a query as the input and displays image content in text outputs and corresponding Images in image outputs.
You can assume there will always be 4 results to output.

My code looks like this:

```
     def gradio_fn(query):
        content, image_paths = answer_question(query) #This is where the image paths are generated
        return content
    
    output_texts = [gr.Textbox() for i in range(4)]    
    input_text = gr.Textbox()
    demo = gr.Interface(
    fn=gradio_fn,
    inputs=input_text,
    outputs=output_texts
)


demo.launch(share = True)
```

where 'image_paths' are paths to the images that i want to output
e.g. '/dbfs/FileStore/d/llm_0.png'

Currently I've only tried to output the text i.e. 'content' and its working (See picture below)

[image]

Now I want to add image outputs next to the text outputs. From my understanding i need to pass the image path to the gradio image function e.g. gr.Image(value= '/dbfs/FileStore/d/llm_0.png')

How can I achieve that when my image paths are generated only after the submit button is clicked?